# C# Random not changing

Tags: c#, .net, random, parallel-processing

I already searched for this question but none of the solutions I found helped. Maybe somebody can help me.

I have the following loop:

```
private static readonly Random RANDOM = new Random();
...
int[] array; // is initialized, when used. ;)
if (array.Sum() != 0)
{
    int j = 0;
    do {
        j = RANDOM.Next(8);
    } while (array[j] == 0);
}
```

This whole loop is in another loop which, again, is in a `Parallel.Foreach`-loop. 
It seems, that `j` is always `0`. Most times it is not noticeable, but if `array[0] == 0`, then it won't get out of the loop. 
I got the suspicion that the `do-while`-loop might be to fast. But also after some seconds (~30) it does not leave the loop. So the `Random` does not seem to return a new or different value (even in the same thread).

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/768001/2395605) but with no effect.

Comment: `System.Random` is not thread safe.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx

Comment: For something missed -- short, _complete_ example we can copy, paste, and run with no modifications is always nice.

Comment: Jon Skeet says it best, as per usual: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the quick answers.
[Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865182/c-sharp-random-not-changing#comment24326819_16865182) already gave me what i needed.
I used

```
public static class RandomGen2 
{ 
    private static Random _global = new Random(); 
    [ThreadStatic] 
    private static Random _local; 

    public static int Next() 
    { 
        Random inst = _local; 
        if (inst == null) 
        { 
            int seed; 
            lock (_global) seed = _global.Next(); 
            _local = inst = new Random(seed); 
        } 
        return inst.Next(); 
    } 
}
```

for my solution. It works very well and quite fast.

Comment: OP, This was the same question that I initially asked you about whether you were locking properly on your shared/static Random instance. You said that you were. That can't have been true because this code clearly does the same thing...

Comment: Does not seem so, because when I tried the other suggestion it didn't work.

Comment: It's not worth arguing, but I am glad that ultimately you got a working solution!

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead, since Random is not thread safe:

```
private static Random RANDOM = new Random();
private static object _randomLock = new object();

...

int[] array; // is initialized, when used. ;)
if (array.Sum() != 0)
{
    int j = 0;
    do {
        lock(_randomLock)
        {
            j = RANDOM.Next(8);
        }
    } while (array[j] == 0);
}
```

Comment: The _randomLock is superfluous: just lock on the static readonly RANDOM instance.

Comment: @DavidH This is true, but for educational purposes, it's good to start out with locking on an empty `object` so that the concept becomes clear, before moving on to explaining that you can, in fact, lock on any static object within scope, not just `object`.

Comment: I 100% agree, thus not downvoting. :)

Comment: as I said, I already tried this version and it didn't work in my code. even so i know the principle of `lock`

Comment: There must be something you've omitted then, because as it stands, that code will produce random numbers even if it is accessed from multiple threads. Have you breakpointed/debugged to see if `j` is actually receiving a value from `RANDOM.Next(8)`? Perhaps try `?RANDOM.Next(8);` in the Immedate window while the program is paused?

Comment: tried the `?RANDOM.Next(8);`. it returned `0` (more than once).

Comment: Wait, I missed this ... why is it marked `readonly`? That's probably why it isn't working, remove that and just make it static.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no difference (i tried it). `readonly` is just not allowing a re-definition of the variable. and a re-definition should not be necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

Random is not threadsafe and isn't sufficiently random for parallel operations. Consider using a thread safe RNG such as [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx), but know that it will be a fair bit slower than Random as the algorithm to generate numbers is much more complex.